# Typescript Arrow Function Parameters with Decorators

Tags: typescript, annotations, metaprogramming, decorator, arrow-functions

Is it possible to currently use decorators against parameters within an arrow function? For example:

```
const func: Function = (@Decorator param: any) => { ... }
```

or

```
class SomeClass {
  public classProp: Function = (@Decorator param: any) => { ... }
}
```

WebStorm doesn't like it, compiler doesn't like it and can't find any documentation online that hints at whether or not this is valid Typescript.

My specific problem is using it within a class as a property but it looks like this problem also extends to standard variable declarations as well.

If this isn't valid, are there any plans to allow this?

Comment: You want a plain arrow function right? Not a class method that is an arrow function?

Comment: The problem I'm running into is using it as a class property (method) but it doesn't look like it works for regular variable declarations either.

Comment: Just curious - for the class method, why do you need it to be an arrow function? To retain context?

Comment: Yeah, I need `this` bound and manually binding in the constructor doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: Can you bind it when using it? Like `let obj = new SomeClass(); let fn = () => obj.classProp();`. Or `let fn = obj.classProp.bind(obj)`?

Comment: I don't have reference to the class outside of the class itself for my issue. I'm actually trying to make a decorator myself that wraps a given class method to do some monitoring. The issue I'm facing is that I need to manually call the original method on the class but since, within decorators, you only have the uninstantiated object at runtime, the methods must be bound so that they carry the correct context with them.

Answer (score -2):

In typescript documentation if I understood you correctly you will find your answer here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

To quote the part relevant:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

const requiredMetadataKey = Symbol("required");

function required(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, parameterIndex: number) {
    let existingRequiredParameters: number[] = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(requiredMetadataKey, target, propertyKey) || [];
    existingRequiredParameters.push(parameterIndex);
    Reflect.defineMetadata(requiredMetadataKey, existingRequiredParameters, target, propertyKey);
}

function validate(target: any, propertyName: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Function>) {
    let method = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function () {
        let requiredParameters: number[] = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(requiredMetadataKey, target, propertyName);
        if (requiredParameters) {
            for (let parameterIndex of requiredParameters) {
                if (parameterIndex >= arguments.length || arguments[parameterIndex] === undefined) {
                    throw new Error("Missing required argument.");
                }
            }
        }

        return method.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

And then use it as such

class Greeter {
       greeting: string;

```
   constructor(message: string) {
       this.greeting = message;
   }

   @validate
   greet(@required name: string) {
       return "Hello " + name + ", " + this.greeting;
   }
```

}

Hope it helps ;)

Seb

Comment: I'm asking specifically about arrow functions, not traditional functions.